# Cannot post a deleted question again

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, 404-not-found

I posted a question on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), then deleted it immediately and clicked on the "edit" link to edit my question. After pressing the "save edits" button, I faced the "404 page not found" error. Then I tried to post the question again in a new post, but I got this error:

> Sorry, this is a duplicate of "Checking if a map is subset of another map"

This is the URL of question I asked and deleted:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/checking-if-a-map-is-subset-of-another-map

So I think this should be a bug. If the question already exists, why couldn't I edit it? And if it does not exist, why can I not post it again?

Comment: Can you see that deleted question?

Comment: @hims056 No I can't. I see the 404 page.

Comment: Ahh.. [OP can't see deleted question by him.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/187824)

Comment: This is now fixed: users can now repost their own deleted questions. However, the cache for this takes a while to update. The updated behavior is described at [Why does a new question "appear to be a duplicate of" a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242347/why-does-a-new-question-appear-to-be-a-duplicate-of-a-deleted-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell by knowing the system for some time, it's by design and not a bug.

1. User with less than 10K reputation can't see deleted questions, not even his own deleted question, so it means he also can't edit such question.
2. Deleted questions still count towards the duplicate check to prevent users from re-posting bad quality questions over and over.

Those two come to protect the community from bad questions, so don't think it will be changed any time soon. Only tip I can give you is to not post the question until you double check it and even if you spot a mistake, don't delete it just edit it.