# Can't submit question, it's a dupe of a deleted question

Tags: bug, asking-questions, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I posted a question, and realised it had some major flaws. The flaws were such that I decided a ninja-edit would take too long, and so just deleted it.

I now can't resubmit my corrected question, as it is a duplicate of the deleted one (which I cannot undelete).

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can't see the image here, but what criteria does it seem to complain about?

Comment: Why can't you edit and undelete the previous one?

Comment: @Bart Because I am not a 10k user on SO.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment The fact that having deleted my own post voluntarily, I cannot post a similar version again, nor can I edit and undelete the first post.

Comment: Hmm, I should start asking questions on SO, so I actually know how that process works. :D

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by creating a different-enough new version of the question (by switching around some code-blocks), then edited the question, once posted, back to its original format.

I've discovered [another variant of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151522/150214) that was closed as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), however I'd like to re-raise this. As a 10k user on other sites, I forgot I wouldn't be able to edit the deleted post, and didn't realise I'd have this duplicate problem. New users presumably wouldn't expect this behaviour anyway. Since there's a clunky way around it anyway, why not turn off de-duplication on owner-deleted questions?

Comment: You could have flagged one of your other posts for for moderation attention and ask the moderators to undelete your question.

Comment: @Yannis This solution is not obvious.

Comment: I never said it was ;)