# Why does a new question "appear to be a duplicate of" a deleted question?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I made a mistake and asked a question with my personal account when I wanted to ask it anonymously. So I deleted the question just after posting, logged off, and then tried to ask it again anonymously.

But when I try to post my question I get the following error:

> This post appears to be a duplicate of ...

And if I click on the link of the question I get

> **Page Not Found**
>
> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Why can I not ask the question if the deleted question is, fortunately, not visible? What is the point of blocking my post?

Maybe I have to wait several minutes/hours/days before asking a question with the same title (even if the first is deleted). But I don't have any further information about this and I think it's a bit disconcerting for the user.

Comment: Might be caching, try again in an hour  or so. No repro here for question that was deleted four hours ago.

Comment: I suppose you don't want to link to the question, because that would defeat the purpose of having asked it anonymously......

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I not ask the question if the deleted question is, fortunately, not visible? What is the point of blocking my post?

The situation you describe is relatively rare. What happens way more often is that a new user posts a crappy question, it gets closed and deleted, and they simply try again. We definitely want to block that, and it's hard for the system to distinguish between both cases, but perhaps it could make an exception and not apply the duplicate check for self-deleted questions with a score of 0 or higher.

Comment: This situation actually resolves itself after a few hours. The cache eventually updates and the error no longer shows up: it's not supposed to include (self-)deleted posts.

Comment: Also, would you mind changing the close reason on [this](/q/370886) to a duplicate of this question? It's currently closed as "no longer reproducible" which is incorrect as it can be reproduced on newer such cases. The off-topic reason overrode the duplicate reason since there were three votes to close as off-topic (two for "no longer reproducible", one as "site-specific", both of which are incorrect). Per the [guidelines](/a/180450/377214), if the duplicate reason applies and no non-duplicate reason applies, the question should be reopened and re-closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog OK, so it's less of a problem than I thought then. Still, it's probably good to have a possible rationale documented somewhere. I've reopened and closed the linked question.